# Ember handlebars and adjacent CSS selector

Tags: css, ember.js, css-selectors, handlebars.js

Ember Handlebars is messing with [adjacent sibling](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector) CSS selectors (`el + el`)

For example, I have list of items:

```
{{#each item in items}}                    
  <span class="item">{{item}}</span>
{{/each}}
```

And I want to add spacing between them with this rule:

```
.item + .item {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

But it doesn't work, because Ember is inserting Metamorph placeholders between items (tags like `<script id="metamorph-1-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>`)

What should I use instead of adjacent sibling selector with handlebars?

Answer (score 2):

Use [general sibling](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector) (or next sibling) selector (`el ~ el`).

Like this:

```
.item ~ .item {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

It will 'skip' Metamorph placeholder tags and any other tags between items.

Comment: This doesn't allow you to select the immediate sibling like the adjacent selector: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

Comment: Yes, it has different semantics, but often it doesn't matter. If it _does_ matter, there is another solution

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Ember.CollectionView`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html) and corresponding helper instead of `{{#each}}`

```
{{#collection contentBinding=items}}                    
  <span class="item">{{this}}</span>
{{/collection}}
```

It will wrap everything in a tag (you can customize it with `tagName` parameter), but it won't insert Metamorph tags between items.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to use the following CSS so that every time the class on the item switched from `.mine` to `.theirs` and vice versa, the position changed. This is the perfect use case for the CSS adjacent sibling selector, but turns out to be slightly complicated to get the markup setup for that selector in ember.

app.css

```
.mine + .theirs,
.theirs + .mine {
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

items.hbs

```
{{#collection Ember.CollectionView
              contentBinding='controller.items'
              itemViewClass='App.ItemView'}}

  markup/content you want inside each EventView e.g., {{ this.name }}

{{/collection}}
```

item_view.js

```
App.ItemView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'span',
  classNames: ['item'],
  classNameBindings: ['side'],
  side: function() {
    // Check a property on the item to see whose it is,
    // set the class accordingly.
    return this.get('context.isTheirs') ? 'theirs' : 'mine';
  }.property()
});
```